# How to center an object between two guidelines in Ai

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I'm using the smart guidelines in Ai artboard and I'm using the align tools.

My question is that "is there any way to move the object between the smart guidelines with the align tool?"

[image]

Comment: I don't catch a question, smart guides are a visual markers that appear only when the some object is moved, what does it meen 'between the smart guidelines'?

Comment: Building off of the previous comment; are you confusing smart guides with the guides that you pull onto the artboard?

Comment: Those aren't "smart guides", they're just regular "guides". But yes, you can just align them with the normal align tools... I think you're actual problem is trying to align with guides *and* the artboard (if I understand what you're trying to do correctly).

Comment: I've update my post with an image, I wish that my question become clear.I might be a bit confused because I'm not designer, I'm very beginner in this beautiful world. Thanks for all of you.

Comment: you are right Cai. You get my point, how can I align an object between two guides. How can I do this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can align using guides with no problem; your issue is trying to align *between* a guide and the *artboard*, I don't think there's directly a way to do that...

What you can do is just snap some guides to the edge of your artboard and use those.

All you need to do then is make sure your guides aren't locked (*View → Guides → Lock Guides*) and use the regular align tools with the guides selected. So to align horizontally between two guides you select the object and the vertical guides on each side and hit the "Horizontal Distribute Center" align button.

See the following for an example:

[image]

Comment: This is very great, thanks a lot. I wish I can give a vote-up  but  unfortunately, I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help